# Marking up the "BBC pattern" in HTML5

Tags: html, markup

I'm looking at the BBC site, and putting together something following a similar overall pattern, and determining how to mark it up appropriately is stumping me somewhat.

The BBC consists of several what could be considered sites in their own right:

- http://www.bbc.co.uk
- http://www.bbc.co.uk/comedy/
- http://www.bbc.co.uk/news/
- www.bbc.co.uk/[a-lot-more-stuff]

*(these could all be subdomains instead - indeed, this is the case for me - but the URLs are not important)*

Each of these is essentially self-contained, with its own content, menu and look and feel. However all of them are tied together by the use of the (slightly variable but mostly) static header bar. This contains the header "BBC" along with links to all of the various sub-sites.

So the question is, how should this be marked up. I see several different options:

1. The main BBC header is the site's main `<header>` and `<nav>`. This is sort of correct, because it is but it ends up essentially de-emphasising the importance of the sub-site's actual content. When it boils down to it (to use the examples above), the title "Comedy" and associated menu is the main content of the page, not the BBC bar.
2. Make the sub-sites' header and navigation the ones which are marked up within `<header>` and `<nav>`. This feels better, but it then opens up the question as to what the BBC bar now is? An option is to use an `<aside>`, which then contains its own `<header>` and `<nav>`. As far as I know, this is fine for the header but having that other `<nav>` element is still weird. Better option than the above?
3. Do the same as number 1 (BBC bar has the main `<header>` and `<nav>`), but mark up the rest of the page inside an `<article>` element. The spec indicates that the article element is to be used for items which make sense on their own, which is the case here. And it'll also make sense for it to have its own `<header>` (and `<nav>`? Is this pushing it somewhat?) But this seems to be stretching the definition of an 'article' rather further than its dictionary definition allows.

To me, having given it some thought and thrown some ideas back and forth on Twitter, number 2 seems the best of these options. However the idea of essentially putting the contents of an `<aside>` as the top element on the page (visually and in markup, since it seems to make most logical sense this way) doesn't quite sit right with me.

Am I overlooking an obvious solution or is this an usual enough pattern that it does make itself as difficult as it seems? And surely I can't be the only one to puzzle over this?

Thanks for any thoughts.

Comment: I wanna see how this pans out, the rules for elements are over-complicated if you ask me.

Answer (score 1):

The main header should be, as you pointed out, marked up in `<header>` and `<nav>`.

I would  then mark each additional page content in an `<article>` containing it's own `<header>` and `<nav>`. Ignore the dictionary definition of article, it doesn't really apply here. It's fine to have more than one `<nav>` element on a page, as long as its contents navigate within the site, that makes sense.

Putting the top header in an `<aside>` also doesn't seem to be correct to me as the content isn't stand alone.

Just my thoughts on the subject!